# How do I use discord.py to add a reaction when function called?

Tags: python, async-await, discord, bots, discord.py

I've been using discord.py, and I want to create a function that reacts with a certain set of emojis when a command is called. Let's say the prefix is `//`.

If I want to call //dinosauce, I want the bot to react with `:thumbsup` and `:thumbsdown`. How do I do this?

This is my code:

```
@client.command()
async def dinosauce(ctx, *, message):
    emojis = [':thumbsup:', ':thumbsdown:']
    await discord.Message.add_reaction(emoji=emojis)
```

Comment: Do you want this on the command message or another message ?

Comment: @Abdulaziz I want it to be on the command message, so if I send `//dinosauce hi` to a channel, the `//dinosauce hi` message will have those reactions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the emoji by using `\:thumbsup:` in discord and copy past that.

```py
@client.command()
async def dinosauce(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('')
    await ctx.message.add_reaction('')
```

In another approach you can make the bot send the message and delete the original one.

```py
@client.command()
async def dinosauce(ctx, *, message):
    await ctx.message.delete()
    msg = await ctx.send(message)
    await msg.add_reaction('')
    await msg.add_reaction('')
```

Reference:

[`Message.add_reaction`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=add_reaction#discord.Message.add_reaction)

Comment: Thanks, this works, but do you know where I can get all the emojis?

Comment: If you don't want to use discord itself. Check out [this website](https://getemoji.com/)